# i m trying to run this code in C++ but showing me error, can you pls tell me the error?

Tags: c++

```
int initfunc(int *array, int len) 
{
    int i;

    for(i=1; i <= len; i++) 
    {
        array[i] = i;
    }

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int *myarray = 0;

    initfunc(myarray, 10);
}
```

Comment: And what was the displayed error?

Comment: I think you should *really, really,* **really [have a look here first](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)**. Not to mention that this belongs to Stack Overflow. Oh, and you did not allocate your memory.

Comment: Should be SO or similar.  Also, I am 'hoping', did you run `make` first?

Comment: There's never memory allocated for `int *myarray = 0;` So what are you actually expecting?

Answer (score -3):

correct code fist:

```
int initfunc(int *array, int len)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 1; i <= len; i++)
    {
        array[i] = i;
        *array++; // this is needed to point to the next position in the array
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int myarray[10];
    /*
    this is an array, int *array is a pointer to int
    but not an actual array
    */

    initfunc(myarray,10);

    return 0;
}
```

the issue with your code is that you are passing a pointer to nothing,
(NUL pointer) declared with the statement: int *array = 0

when you pass that to a function that store ten values
that is the recipe for a disaster because it points to a storage
that was not allocated first.

I hope this helps.

Comment: This program segfaults :) This is not how arrays work. `*array++` isn't needed, it's deadly. You're basically changing the array's first cell's address (at least the pointer to it), causing the loop to go out of bounds, into forbidden address space.

Comment: Another note: `i = 1; i <= len; i++` is wrong; C++ is 0-indexed. You want `i = 0; i < len; i++)`

Comment: `for(i = 1; i <= len; i++)` this is inducing physical pains for me. Please delete this crap!